# Cypress with Docker and Jenkins pipeline. String does not match pattern error message

Tags: docker, docker-compose, automated-tests, cypress

I'm doing a cypress 6+ training course and I'm trying to run a Jenkins pipeline  using docker.  My terminal displayed the following message.  I'm trying to figure out how to fix this.

```
{
    "resource": "/Users/xxx/Documents/CypressDocker_JenkinsPipeline/package.json",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "String does not match the pattern of \"^(?:@[a-z0-9-*~][a-z0-9-*._~]*/)?[a-z0-9-~][a-z0-9-._~]*$\".",
    "startLineNumber": 2,
    "startColumn": 11,
    "endLineNumber": 2,
    "endColumn": 26
}
```

There appeared to be an issue with the package json so I took a look at it.  I honestly can't see what the problem is and would love another pair of eyes to take a look.

```
    {
  "name": "CypressDocker_JenkinsPipeline",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress run",
    "headTest": "npm run test -- --headed ",
    "choromeTest": "npm run test -- --browser chrome ",
    "build:and:test": "npm run cy:run start-server-and-test start https://react-redux.realworld.io/ cy:run"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to updated the script 'build:and:test',
I see issue with launch cypress - the correct command should be

```
npm run cy:run
```

Please share the link to course

Comment: thanks for responding. so are you saying the command in the package.json  should be     "build:and:test": "npm run cy:run start-server-and-test start https://react-redux.realworld.io/ cy:run"

Comment: I think first you need to configure scenario based on cypress - [link](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/writing-your-first-test#Add-a-test-file)
after reconfigure the script block in the package.json - [link](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress#Adding-npm-scripts)
I can't see any configuration in your package.json for launch the local server.

Comment: I've updated the package.json (in my original question). Still getting the same problem

Comment: Looked into the initial question - few steps need to update:- (install package) npm install --save-dev start-server-and-test
- add a script into json file ("start": "my-server -p 3030")
- update the script "build:and:test" - I think in this way
"start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3030 test"
- trigger the script with npm 'npm run build:and:test'
@fypnlp

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what went wrong. I copied the file from another file and I hadn't created a NEW package.json file.  So When I saved the file the package.json was for the original file and did not reflect the changes in the NEW file. So cypress was confused as to what was happening.

Then, I created a new package.json file it contained the correct information, I added the commands to run the cypress scripts (headed, Chrome and Docker). Saved it, restarted VS code and the error went away.

I also modified Build and test.  So the code now reads in the package.json

```
"build:and:test": "npm run start-server-and-test start https://react-redux.realworld.io/ cy:run"
```

Just getting it double checked that the command is right.